# php exec() run Rscript successfully by cmd line but not working by browser

Tags: php, r, linux, server

I am trying to write a web app to run my R script.
I plan to use php shell_exec() to make this happen.

I wrote a test script like this 
`<?php echo shell_exec("Rscript /var/www/html/demo/MyRScript.R"); ?>`

I run it through command line.
`php test.php`, it gives right output, I also observe through `htop` and found the process was using 100% cpu for couple of minutes.

However, when I tried to run it through visiting it through browser, through the address `http://myURL/demo/test.php`. It didn't run properly, it only gives first few line of my R script `onbrief Off On FALSE 405 0 TRUE 0 405 petitioner P R FALSE 0 396 TRUE 414 0`and stopped immediately. I cannot find that process through `htop` either.

I have tried other simple command line like `ls`, `rm`, they all work properly both on cmd line and through web app.

I have no idea what is wrong. Can it because the process takes too much CPU, so some mechanism will terminate it if it is call by web?

Or if there is any debug tool or method I can use to help me find the problem.

This is my first question on Stack overflow, I don't know if my information is enough. please tell me if there is other more information needed to tackle the problem.

Thank you so much.

Comment: CMD is the Windows' shell. Nothing to do with Linux.

Comment: opps, I thought is was the same thing with command line.

Comment: There is a Command-line tag, but it doesn't seem useful.

Comment: try adding "2>&1" to the end of your command - you will see the errors right there (if any), maybe not a good solution for production, but may help in dev environment. there might be some EOF in the output. The execution time is also might be an issue as you described your top goes 100% for couple minutes and default php max_execution_time is only 30 seconds.

Comment: Thank you ksiv! After add "2>&1" I am able to find the errors and solve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

It turn out to be the file permission problem.

In my R script, there is a line trying to access a file, while the web server user `www-data` do not have permission to read. After grant the permission to it, everything goes fine.

Adding `2>$1` at the end of my command is very useful, I am able to get the error message in my browser.